# Como Exibir consulta SQL em um Array

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou com uma dúvida. Quando eu rodo um Select Count no banco de dados ele exibe tudo certinho. Mas como exibir da mesma forma usando PHP?

```
select country, count(*) as quantidade from customer group by country
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$sql=mysql_query("select country, count(*) as quantidade from customer group by country");
```

E depois eu não sei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$arr = array();
$sql=mysql_query("select country, count(*) as quantidade from customer group by country");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $arr [$row ["country"]] = $row["quantidade"];
}
```

Dessa maneira, será criado um array onde o nome dos países são as chaves e as quantidades são os valores.

Nesse link há mais informações sobre o comando [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 1):

tente usar o comando mysql_fetch_array:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select country, count(*) as quantidade from customer group by country");
$exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
            echo $exibe["country"];
```

Aí é só colocar dentro de um loop e fazer alguns testes.

Comment: Estou tentando construir o loop mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `print_r` com o retorno do banco dentro de tags HTML `<pre>` da seguinte forma:

```
$query=mysql_query("select country, count(*) as quantidade from customer group by country");
$valores = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($valores);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Quando eu uso o print_r ele só exibe a primeira linha.